# how to remove the Brackets in a json file at the end and beginning in Apache Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi

i have a json file like this one below and try to remove the array's brackets at the beginning and the end

```json
[
  {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2"
  }
]
```

and i only want the map:

```json
{
  "a": "1",
  "b": "2"
}
```

anyone knows which processor to use and how to configure?
Thanks, Lukas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative way might be adding a **JoltTransformJSON** processor which will contain this spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Where you know the commands of jolttransformjson from?

Comment: you^re welcome @lrf , You can check out [the link 1](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt) and [the link 2](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/releases/tag/jolt-0.1.1) , and this is the [playground](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/). And such a nice [tutorial](https://intercom.help/godigibee/en/articles/3159219-transformer-operations-overview). Best wishes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SplitJson Processor.

I've used the following settings for the Processor.

[image: Configuration for SplitJson processor]

Or you can also use EvaluateJsonPath. Here is my configuration for EvaluateJsonPath.

[image: Configuration for EvaluateJsonPath processor]